# Initializing values to a custom data type

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, datatypes, plsql-developer

I have defined a custom data type which I need to use in my procedure. Give below is my data type.

```
CREATE or REPLACE TYPE CUSTOM_DATATYPE AS object(
chkinvpre    VARCHAR2(100),
orderid      NUMBER(10),
deldate      DATE,
fowno        VARCHAR2(40),
fowname      VARCHAR2(40),
fowadd1      VARCHAR2(40),
fowadd2      VARCHAR2(40),
fowadd3      VARCHAR2(40),
fowadd4      VARCHAR2(40),
packtype     VARCHAR2(40),
noofpacktype VARCHAR2(40),
gweight      VARCHAR2(40),
dimension    VARCHAR2(40),
hawb         VARCHAR2(40) 
)
NOT final;
```

Now, I am trying to initialize this data type to call my  procedure . Given below is the code.

```
declare 
rajesh CUSTOM_DATATYPE;
begin
 rajesh:=('xyz',123,'13-02-14','12','fdfd','add1','add2','add3','add4','packtype','noofpacktype','1234','dfs','dde');   
  DN_Generated(rajesh);
end;
```

/

And here is the error that I am getting.

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
declare 
rajesh CUSTOM_DATATYPE;
begin
 rajesh:=('xyz',123,'13-02-14','12','fdfd','add1','add2','add3','add4','packtype','noofpacktype','1234','dfs','dde');   
  DN_Generated(rajesh);
end;
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 10:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 4, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Please let me know the error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing the datatype before the initialization of the type/object.  See the updated (but untested code below).

[Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjplsql.htm#ADOBJ07002)

```
declare 
    rajesh CUSTOM_DATATYPE;
begin
    rajesh := CUSTOM_DATATYPE('xyz',123,'13-02-14','12','fdfd','add1','add2','add3','add4','packtype','noofpacktype','1234','dfs','dde');   
      DN_Generated(rajesh);
end;
```